# Google Analytics Ecommerce, viewing Product Performance chart by Product Category Level 1 only

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

Our WordPress Ecommerce website has first level categories named after US State names.

Under the the category, there are subcategories such as "Packages", "Property", "Annuities" and etc.

So the category structure would look somewhat like this:

- Alabama

  - Packages
  - Property
- Arkansas

  - Packages
  - Property
- Georgia

  - Packages
  - Property

Now, when I run a report, the report automatically shows category by level 2.

Refer to the picture below:
(CONVERSIONS - Ecommerce - Product Performance)

[image: Google Analytics Ecommerce chart]

I put secondary dimension as "product category level 1", but the listings are still divided by the "product category level 2".

What I want is to view the items by the Category Level 1. I have been trying to find a way to sort the items by the Product Category Level 1 only, but it always come up as Category level 2.

Is there anyway to view the items only by the category level 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pivot function of GA to get the result you need. You find it on the right over the table you see:

[image]

There you can Pivot the Data by "product category level 1",

Comment: sorry for the late reply.  What if the pivot table doesn't show "product category level 1"?  Under Pivot by: dropdown menu, I see Product, Product Brand, Product SKU and Product Variant.  I don't see product category level 1 option here unfortunately :(